# HttpPost in third party application [Android]

Tags: android, http, http-post

I try to make an app as a mobile version of some site, which requires authorization. 
Here is the login form of the site

```
<form method="post" 
    action="loginAuth.php" 
    autocomplete="off">
    <input id="username" 
        name="username" 
        type="text" 
        class="inp" />
    <input id="password" 
        name="password" 
        type="password" 
        class="inp" />
    <input type="submit" 
        class="q-button" 
        name="LogIn" 
        value=" Log In"/>
</form>
```

And here is my code:

```
public String postData() {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url + "loginAuth.php");
    try {
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, "UTF-8"));

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        if (entity != null) {
            String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
            return responseBody;
        } else {
            return null;
        }

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

The problem is that I can't authorize and the `postData()` method returns me authorization page again.

Comment: and what's your question?

Comment: Budius, The problem is that I can't authorize and the postData() method returns me authorization page again. 
I want to authorize, but I can't

Comment: the point is: The proper way apps access stuff in the cloud is through a public API and using their own application KEY. What you're trying to achieve is a hacky workaround, and there's just so much you can do with hacky workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

You should to make sure that this website doesn't use SSL and if that you can't make SSL request without their certificate

Comment: Thank you. Is there another method to make the request without certificate?